# Spectral data to XYZ color model in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, colors, rgb, spectrum

I'm working in MATLAB, trying to take the reflection spectrum of a sample and display the perceived color, as an approximation.

I used the 2-deg XYZ CMFs transformed from the CIE (2006) 2-deg LMS cone fundamentals with 0.1nm step size from http://cvrl.ioo.ucl.ac.uk/cmfs.htm as my color matching functions.

I used the three formulae shown here: http://www.fourmilab.ch/documents/specrend/

I think it should be pretty straightforward, but somehow I keep getting Z values around 120 for the spectrum I'm evaluating, which is higher than the allowed range for Z.

To get higher accuracy, I tried interpolating my matching functions, but I got very similar results than what I did previously.

```
function [X,Y,Z, RGB] = spectrumtoXYZ(P, Lambda, x, y, z)

% - P is the spectrum
% - Lambda is the wavelength for which I have my matching function data
%   points
% - x,y,z are the matching functions

X=0;Y=0;Z=0;

%Delta Lambda as specified here https://www.fourmilab.ch/documents/specrend/
del = (P(end,1)-P(1,1))/length(P);

for i=1:length(P)   
    %I look for the closest wavelength available in the matching function
    [~, j] = min(abs(P(i,1)-Lambda));
    fx=0;fy=0;fz=0;

    % Linear interpolation of Lambda for better integral accuracy
    if (P(i,1)-Lambda(j))>0 && j~=length(Lambda)
        fx=x(j)+(x(j+1)-x(j))/(Lambda(j+1)-Lambda(j))*(P(i,1)-Lambda(j));
        fy=y(j)+(y(j+1)-y(j))/(Lambda(j+1)-Lambda(j))*(P(i,1)-Lambda(j));
        fz=z(j)+(z(j+1)-z(j))/(Lambda(j+1)-Lambda(j))*(P(i,1)-Lambda(j));
    end

    if (P(i,1)-Lambda(j))<=0 && j~=1
        fx=x(j)+(x(j)-x(j-1))/(Lambda(j)-Lambda(j-1))*(P(i,1)-Lambda(j));
        fy=y(j)+(y(j)-y(j-1))/(Lambda(j)-Lambda(j-1))*(P(i,1)-Lambda(j));
        fz=z(j)+(z(j)-z(j-1))/(Lambda(j)-Lambda(j-1))*(P(i,1)-Lambda(j));
    end

    %Integral
    X=del*fx*P(i,2)+X;
    Y=del*fy*P(i,2)+Y;
    Z=del*fz*P(i,2)+Z;
end

% X,Y,Z to RGB; Ref. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space
M=[0.41847 -0.15866 -0.082835; -0.091169 0.25243 0.015708; 0.00092090 -0.0025498 0.17860];
RGB = M*[X;Y;Z];
end
```

Is there a blatant mistake in my reasoning/code? I've been staring at this for hours. Any ideas of what I could test to troubleshoot?

Comment: I'm looking at this now.  BTW, did you see the companion C code on the website you referenced? http://www.fourmilab.ch/documents/specrend/specrend.c

Comment: Yes, I did! The equations are essentially the same, but the implementation is different. I tried using Planck's radiation law and I'm getting the same x, y, z as him. I think that the XYZ values I'm getting might be the right one. This software should be doing what I'm looking for: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29620-cie-coordinate-calculator
But I kept getting errors with my spectrum, so I decided to do one myself. When using the spectrum data from that file, I get the same X,Y, Z values. However, I've seen on several websites that X<95, Y<100, Z<108. Thank you.

Comment: I'd question whatever website said that X, Y and Z are limited. Y is luminance, in units of nits. I had one case where I had input a sodium lamp's data, and got a Y value around 8,000. It sounded vaguely believable because newer HDR monitors can display up to the thousands of nits, while values around 0.1 are considered dark enough to call "black". But I've never seen a spectrum and the correct expected result of integrating it, so I can't tell if my logic is correct yet.